# Webview doesn't run local javascript

Tags: android, android-webview

I load html from assets, and it runs properly, but the javascript file seems doesn`t run. I put alert(1) there to test, rebuild my app and nothing happens. In the same time javascript runs from the web, if I connect to the site with the same files(index.html, fun.js). So the web page(html) is running, but javascript(from file, that linked via  tag) is not running.

MainAcivity.java

```
    WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if( activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected())
    {myWebView.loadUrl("http://load_real_site.com");}
    else
    {myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in javascript file. Seems, the problem was in declaring an array as var a=[];, although it worked in web. Making var a=[0]; solved the problem and javascript ran.